# kotlin; group by multiple fields

Tags: kotlin

How can I do a groupBy in my code by three or more fields?
My code is like below:

```
val nozzleSaleReport = nozzleStateList.groupBy {
    {it.shift.id},{it.createUser.id},{it.nozzle.id} // Here I need to add these three fields for grouping operation
}.map { entry ->
    val max: Float = (entry.value.maxBy { it.nozzleState.finalLitreMechanical }?.nozzleState!!.finalLitreMechanical ?: 0).toString().toFloat()
    val min: Float = (entry.value.minBy { it.nozzleState.finalLitreMechanical }?.nozzleState!!.finalLitreMechanical ?: 0).toString().toFloat()

    NozzleSaleReport(entry.value[0].createUser.name, entry.value[0].shift.name,  (max - min).toInt(),entry.value[0].shift.id, entry.value[0].nozzle.id, entry.value[0].nozzle.name)
}.let {
    println(it)
}
```

Comment: Create a Key data class with those three properties, create an (extension) method transforming en element of the collection into a Key, and group by Key.

Comment: Would you please provide an example?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's say the class of the elements of your collection is `NozzleState`.

You want to group nozzle states by shift ID, create user ID and nozzle ID.

If I understand correctly, you thus want a different group for each distinct combination of shift ID, create user ID and nozzle ID.

So you need to create a class representing such a combination (let's name if `Key`), and group the elements by their `Key`:

```
data class Key(val shiftId: String, val createUserId: String, val nozzleId: String)
fun NozzleState.toKey() = Key(shift.id, createUser.id, nozzle.id)

nozzleStateList.groupBy { it.toKey() }
```

Comment: could it be an anonymous class?

Comment: How would you invoke its constructor if it doesn't have a name?

Comment: I'm c# developer. There is a new {} pattern which creates anonymous object and can be accessed in the expression

Comment: You could use a List as the Key, but I find it less clean: nozzleStateList.groupBy { listOf(it.shiftId, it.createUser.id, it.nozzle.id) }

Comment: Wow! great. Thank you very much

Comment: Besides [`Pair`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html), Kotlin has also a [`Triple`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/index.html) data class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Pair or Triple(in your usecase) provided by Kotlin. Here is a sample code that might be of some help:

```
items = items.groupBy { Pair(it.productId, it.batchId) }
        .values
        .map {
            it.reduce { accumulator, item ->
                item.copy(quantity = accumulator.quantity + item.quantity)
            }
        }
```